# Основы PHP и array_rand

Tags: php

Друзья, добрый день помогите с вопросом:

хочу из массива вывести ответ случайным образом, но выводит его индекс, а не значение?

```
$ans = array (

1 => 'да',
    2 => 'нет',
    3 => 'никогда',
    4 => 'очень скоро',
    5 => 'забудь',
    6 => 'зачем тебе?'
);
$vopros = 'Выучу ли я анgлийский';
$random = array_rand($ans);
$otvet = $random;

echo "Вопрос: {$vopros}<br/>";
echo "ответ: {$otvet}<br/>";
```

ответ выводит такой:

> Вопрос: Выучу ли я анgлийский
>
> ответ: 1

Comment: `$ans[$random]`?

Comment: echo "ответ: {$ans[$random]}<br/>" как товарищ выше подсказал

Comment: @WlodzimierzSitdikowski можете опубликовать как ответ, только с более подробным объяснением почему так ;-)

Comment: получилось верно, но не пойму где логика... объясните пожалуйста

Comment: логика в том что функция array_rand возвращает ключ массива. Поэтому чтобы получить нужное значение нужно обратиться к ячейке массива по ключу который вернула функция array_rand. ИЗ php.net - "Выбирает одно или несколько случайных значений из массива. Возвращает ключ (или ключи) данных случайных элементов."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все правильно.

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-rand.php

> Возвращает **ключ (или ключи)** данных случайных элементов.

```
$otvet = $ans[$random];
```

Comment: так тоже верно, объясните почему в квадратных скобках переменная?

Comment: мы берем элемент массива $ans с ключом $random

Comment: @KBMira в `$random` хранится число. А у массивов обратиться к элементу массива можно через квадратные скобки...например `$ans[1]` или `$ans['myCustomKey']` .... в итоге если допустим в `$random` число 1, то `$ans[$random]` будет равна такой  `$ans[1]`...... то есть вместо переменной что-то подставляется... вообще так можно очень много вложить чего `$array[$array2[$array3['key'][2]]['something']]` ... правда будет нечитаемо...но тем не менее